# handle docker container data while developing wep application

Tags: docker, docker-container

I pulled this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ilampirai/docker-magento2/) for magento2 installation.

Now I am trying to get container **/var/www/html** data in host after that I can handle with phpstorm.

I tried like this but it overwrite everything in container /var/www/html

```
docker run --name development-phase -d -p 5000:80 -v /u01/magento2:/var/www/html magento2
```

**while creating volume**

**data flows:** from  host /u01/magento2 to container /var/www/html

but I am looking

**data flow should be** from  container /var/www/html to host /u01/magento2

I have referred some stack overflow link all are suggest copy container data to host before creating volume, in my case docker cp command affect some prerequisite setting of magento2 so the page get not load properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the behavior of volumes in Docker:

- `-v /host/path:/container/path` does not copy data
- `-v /container/path` will copy data and creates new volume with a random name

So, you might want to try

```
docker run --name development-phase -d -p 5000:80 -v /var/www/html magento2
```

Then find out the random path looking at the value of property `Source` for the `"Destination":"/var/www/html"` using `docker inspect`

```
docker inspect --format "{{json .Mounts}}" development-phase
```

Even more readable with

```
docker inspect -f "{{json .Mounts}}" development-phase \
 | jq '.[] | select(.Destination | contains("/var/www/html"))'
```